# Text classification using tf idf

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, text-mining, overfitting, tf-idf

I am developing a text classification model. At this moment I have to classify some documents in six different classes. I am using a simple approach as a starting point based on random forests over a tf idf matrix.

Basically a get a sample of documents and I create a tf-idf matrix from their vocabulary. Then I train the algorithm with this data.

To test my results I need to transform the test documents to s 'tf-idf vectorized representation'. How is this usually done? Should I use the training set together with the test to compute this values? Wouldn't I committing overfitting?

Comment: The same way you did with training ?